# How to bind multiple strings into 1 variable in a cursor?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to bind the string of one variable into another variable, repeating for each cursor.

I currently have this:

```
DECLARE curA CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT A FROM TableA

OPEN curA   
FETCH NEXT FROM curA INTO @varA
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN 
        ........            
        FETCH NEXT FROM curA INTO @varA
    END

CLOSE curA
```

Now I want all the records of @varA (@varA is in string) in the cursor to concatenate into @varB, for example: @varB = 'Acbd, efgh, xyz...'

How can I do it?

Comment: Edit the question add some sample data & desired result would helpful.

Comment: A `CURSOR` is the wrong approach here. It is the wrong approach in most cases actually. Try to avoid cursors if ever possible. Which version of sql-server... You might read about `STRING_AGG()` (v2017+). With older versions there is the XML-based approach (see the existing answer)

Answer (score 1):

I would use `FOR XML PATH()` clause instead of `cursor` or `looping` :

```
SELECT @varA = STUFF( (SELECT ', '+A
                       FROM tablea
                       FOR XML APTH('')
                      ), 1, 1, ''
                    );
```

Comment: Hi, is there any way to do it inside the cursor?

Comment: @VũTrần may I ask why? Anything is better than a cursor. Even a *quirky update* was better...

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want can be created by the following code line:
`SET @varB = @varA + ',' + @varB`
And after the cursor, remove the last "," from @varB.
I assumed you are using SQL Server.